# Unfamiliar characters in a script tag from a Google page...not quite sure what to call it

Tags: javascript, src

I was watching "The story of Send" by Google and the animation fascinated me so I viewed the generated code (in Firefox) towards the end of the head (approx line 15) I noticed this:

```
<script async="" src="https://apis.google.com/_/apps-static/_/js/gapi/plusone/rt=j/ver=toCY55Mwojo.en./sv=1/am=%21wIVbqfszG0CYZd2EOQ/d=1/rs=AItRSTPQF97pO4HWCKrkiNkssFYE0VuEnw/cb=gapi.loaded_0"></script>
```

What are the underscores in between some of the slashes in the URL?

I have never seen that before so I don't even know what to call it.

From:
http://www.google.com/green/storyofsend/desktop/#/smart-heat

Also, is this the correct way to use (or in this case not use) the 'async' attribute?

I had just been adding "async" to the script tag, but I am a JS noob.

Comment: Wow, that was a prompt and concise answer...didn't know you could do that but fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the underscores in between some of the slashes in the URL?

They are underscores. There is absolutely nothing special about them. Google could have used `a` there instead if they wanted.

> Also, is this the correct way to use (or in this case not use) the 'async' attribute?

No. It is a boolean attribute.

```
<script async>
```

or

```
<script async="async">
```

Comment: Is there any reason--I dunno maybe semantics--that an underscore should be used for a folder name?

Comment: "There is absolutely nothing special about them", so no (and equally no reason why they should not be used)